# sticky image in html taking up space in the header

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a sticky image which i am trying to place above my nav bar, the code for sticky is like below:

```css
img.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="index.html" rel="home" class="logo logo_image_only">
    <img class="sticky" src="assets/img/logo_n.png" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

here is my navbar css

```css
.navbar-area {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar-area.is-sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 28px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 28px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  -webkit-animation: 500ms ease-in-out 0s normal none 1 running fadeInDown;
  animation: 500ms ease-in-out 0s normal none 1 running fadeInDown;
}

.navbar-area.is-sticky .zash-nav .navbar {
  -webkit-box-shadow: unset;
  box-shadow: unset;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.navbar-area.navbar-style-two {
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.navbar-area.navbar-style-two .zash-nav {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-area.navbar-style-two .zash-nav .navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: unset;
  box-shadow: unset;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

now when i load the page, the image is not proper, its taking up space and making my nav bar go wrong like the image below:

[image]
 can anyone please tell me whats wrong ? thanks in advance

Comment: What's your css for your navbar ?

Comment: Do u have a codepen?

Comment: @DylanKas i have updated the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make the position "sticky" to "fixed" for the image, Please refer below code.

```
img.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Hello @kingkhankkhan, If your issue is solved then please accept my answer, thanks